# How to make Photoshop use multiple windows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm starting to use Photoshop CS 6, coming from CS 3. The older version has an option to use multiple windows (one per document) with floating palettes. Is this arrangement available in Photoshop CS 6?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: @DanielLawson I'm surprised that second bit (which all the answers ignored) stuck around to now, to be honest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the Window menu and un-check the Application Frame menu item. The palettes will pop to the edges of your screen and the documents will turn into floating windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the file tab and select `Move to New Window` individually. Or in Preferences > Interface, deselect `Open Documents as Tabs` to stop the tab behavior.

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the grey background that hides everything else. Is there some way to have a document window with floating palette windows on the screen edges like in Illustrator CS 6?